# Using dropins in a web app not running in the cloud

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to use the Dropbox drop-ins in one of my projects. It is a web application that should be able to be run locally without a web server. I am using the Dropbox chooser, but it gives an error if it is not running on a web server. It says "invalid origin". Is it possible to get rid of this error without using a local web server to run the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to run a local server. Each domain you serve your page from has to be entered in the App console. "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" will work, but those require you to actually run a local web server. (It doesn't have to be a complicated web server... `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` would work.)